# Directly put a global object to a HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, function, object-literal, createelement

Here is my code :

```
document._createELement = document.createElement;
document.createElement = function(type, data){
    var x = document._createElement(type);
    x = data;

    return x;
}
```

And I tried this :

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p", {
    innerHTML: "Hi!"
}));
```

And I expect to see this in the HTML :

```
<p>Hi!</p>
```

What's the solution to complete the `document.createElement` function above?

Comment: Why you expect `{innerHTML:"Hi!"}` in some mysterious way to change to `<p>Hi!</p>`???

Comment: So now, I've got "Hi!" in `data` and I want to put `data` into `x` so that `x.innerHTML = data.innerHTML` but I must be able to add all kinds of attribute in `data` such as `style`, `className`, `id`, etc.

Comment: Yes, yes I did. That's why I'm asking. At first you assign a HTMLElement to `x`, then on the next line you assign an anonymous object to that same `x`.

Comment: Just enumerate the properties of `data` and assign it to `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just wanting to create a `p` element and append to the body, this will do it

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = "Hello!";
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

**EDIT**

Missunderstood you mean this

```
function createEl(type, data) {
    var el = document.createElement(type);
    for ( var x in data ) {
      el[x] = data[x];
    };
    return el;
}

var p = createEl("p", { innerHTML : "Hi There!" });
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rq7pG/1/)

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. The problem is at the function `document.createElement` which I created.